# how to send thumb images in telethon, python

Tags: python, telethon

My code is
`async for message in client.iter_messages(-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx): if message.document: print("Documento: \n", str(message.document)); # Downloading to memory blob = await client.download_media(message, bytes);#Download file ok #I extract the file name filename_attr = next(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, DocumentAttributeFilename),            message.document.attributes), None); filename = filename_attr.file_name if filename_attr else 'Unknown'; print("Filename: ", filename); #OK`

??
message.document is:
Documento:
`Document(id=5870898922704080833, access_hash=-1634122875322818687,       file_reference=b'\x02s,\xf22\x00\x00\r\x0cd\xae\xab\xbb\xe5B\xd4\xdf\x1d\xf3\xf9d~V\xcd\xa9=\x14  \xb1\xab', date=datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 12, 4, 36, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), mime_type='application/pdf', size=27397669, dc_id=4, attributes=[DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name='12-07-23-zzz.pdf')], thumbs=[PhotoStrippedSize(type='i', bytes=b"\x01((\xd7'\xe6\xc6\x7fJuE!U?4\xa5\t\xe82*<\xabe|\xec\xe7\x8cn\x1c\xfe\x94\x08ArJLA\\\xaa\xefLzR\xf9\xec\x1fa\xc6I\\\x121\xd7?\xe1Mo)\xfe\xf4\xc0\xf1\x8f\xbc:\x1f\xc2\x82\x91`\xa9\x94\x1d\xde\xac\x0e\x7fJ\x00\xb27\x0c\xe4\xee\xf4\xc0\xc5\x15\x02\xf9j\x00Y\xfa\xff\x00\xb4?\xc2\x8a\x00\x92T\xdc\xd9,q\xe8\x00\xa6y}\xf7\xb6q\xe8)\xcc_\xcd 7\x1d\x85E$\xa6$-#\x907c\x8eh\x18\xe3\x17\x18\x0eF?\xd9\x14y\\xe7\xcco\xc8TB\xed\t\x18\x9b$\xf4\x05i\xb2\xdd<J2H\x07\xd0P\x05\x83\x1eG.\xdf\x90\xa2\x9b\x04\xcc\xf1\x82\xbc\x928\x04\xf5\xa2\x95\xc2\xc4wWQ\xc51B\xc3~:Us.@\xde\x18\xa9\xe4\xfc\xb4QC\x1av\x1a\x16&\x90\x84\x1ft\xe4s\xefKtZE\x1c\x0f\x97\xa8\x06\x8a(\x1b\xdc}\xbf1\xa6\x1biV\xc19\xc7z(\xa2\x99'"), PhotoSize(type='m', w=320, h=320, size=32037)], video_thumbs=[])`

How can I extract thumbs data to send in send_file??

`await client.send_file('+34629060331', blob,caption="Ole!!!",  attributes=     [DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name=filename)], thumb= ?????, progress_callback=callback);`

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.